# Is it bad practice to have multiple Jquery click events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it bad practice to have multiple Jquery click events?

Hi new dev here! As a new developer I'm trying to get rid of any bad habit I have, and something I always cringe at that I do is multiple click events. For some reason I always feel like there is a neater way of doing it. Is it normal in your experience to see this sort of code? Is it bad? Please let me know! (Note: the $(denim-overlay-section).toggle() is for text that's different for every section. So denim has a denim blurb, comfort has a comfort blurb etc)   The .active class changes a plus button image to a minus button image.

```
$('#denim-overlay-section, #true-overlay-section, #comfort-overlay-section, #jegging-overlay-section, #tummy-overlay-section, #chambray-overlay-section')
    .hide();

$('#classicBtn').click(function () {
    $('#denim-overlay-section').toggleClass('denim-overlay');
    $('#denim-overlay-section').toggle();
    $('.plusBtn-classic').toggleClass('active');
});
$('#trueBtn').click(function () {
    $('#true-overlay-section').toggleClass('denim-overlay');
    $('#true-overlay-section').toggle();
    $('.plusBtn-true').toggleClass('active');
});
$('#comfortBtn').click(function () {
    $('#comfort-overlay-section').toggleClass('denim-overlay');
    $('#comfort-overlay-section').toggle();
    $('.plusBtn-comfort').toggleClass('active');
});
$('#jeggingBtn').click(function () {
    $('#jegging-overlay-section').toggleClass('denim-overlay');
    $('#jegging-overlay-section').toggle();
    $('.plusBtn-jegging').toggleClass('active');
});
$('#tummyBtn').click(function () {
    $('#tummy-overlay-section').toggleClass('denim-overlay');
    $('#tummy-overlay-section').toggle();
    $('.plusBtn-tummy').toggleClass('active');
});
$('#chambrayBtn').click(function () {
    $('#chambray-overlay-section').toggleClass('denim-overlay');
    $('#chambray-overlay-section').toggle();
    $('.plusBtn-chambray').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: It's not a foul per say, there's much worse. If you'd like to however you could do a window click event and check the event for the ID's and possibly make it a function call.

Comment: **yes**, you could reduce all that code to one event by using classes, then [finding](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the other items to toggle

Comment: Give all the buttons the same class so you can target them as one. Then you can get the ID of the section to toggle with `this.id.replace("Btn", "-overlay-section")`

Comment: Protip: Avoid IDs in jQuery and avoid them in CSS. Make your code reusable.

Comment: *data driven development* is what you're looking for.  Write your code so it doesn't know what goes with what and connect using `data-` attributes.  That way you can add new buttons and related sections without needing to add any new code, and it "just works".